# How many times does each element appear in the column it exists in?

Tags: r

Here is my data-frame:

```
a d c
d a b
b e c 
e b b
c c e
f f d
```

In this data-frame, I want to know:
How many times does each element appear in the column it exists in?
Then I want to store them in a matrix.
So the matrix looks like this:

```
1 1 0
1 1 2
1 1 2
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1
```

Does anyone have any simple pieces of code to do this? Thanks for everyone's help.

Another data-frame

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
 [3,]   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1
 [4,]   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1
 [5,]    2    2   -2    1   -1   -1
 [6,]    2    2   -2    1   -1   -1
 [7,]   -2   -2    2    1   -1   -1
 [8,]   -2   -2    2    1   -1   -1
 [9,]    3   -3    3   -1    1   -1
[10,]    3   -3    3   -1    1   -1
[11,]   -3    3   -3   -1    1   -1
[12,]   -3    3   -3   -1    1   -1
[13,]    4   -4   -4   -1   -1    1
[14,]    4   -4   -4   -1   -1    1
[15,]   -4    4    4   -1   -1    1
[16,]   -4    4    4   -1   -1    1
```

Is that okay to use `do.call(cbind, tapply(unlist(df), gl(ncol(df),nrow(df)), table))`

Comment: Your data doesn't look like a `data.frame`. It's a matrix. First do: `df <- as.data.frame(your_matrix)`. Then do: `df[] <- lapply(df, as.factor)`. Then try the `do.call(cbind, ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically just need to call `table` on each column:

```
df = read.table(text="a d c
d a b
b e c 
e b b
c c e
f f d", header=FALSE)

df_counts = lapply(
  df,
  function(x) {
    table(factor(x, levels=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")))
  }
)
df_counts = matrix(unlist(df_counts), ncol=3)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    2
[3,]    1    1    2
[4,]    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    1
[6,]    1    1    0
```

---

A slightly different implementation on the same idea:

```
do.call(cbind, tapply(unlist(df), gl(ncol(df),nrow(df)), table))
```

Comment: +1 and to more easily get the factor levels you could use `unique(unlist(df))`

Comment: @Arun, Could you please demonstrate the code you gave with this case?       
`do.call(cbind, tapply(unlist(df), gl(ncol(df),nrow(df)), table))`
I have some trouble with this.         There seems to be something contradicts with my results.
Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Could you give your example that contradicts your results (by editing your post)? I assume that all columns of your data.frame are factors. For every column of your data.frame I just call a `table` and then bind them together. That is, `gl` takes care of sending each column of your `unlisted` data.frame to get `table`.